# Nested experimental design of a drug screening using lmer in R

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, biostatistics

I'm a bit stuck with the best formula to use in the `lmer` to analyze my data.
The effect on behavior (ALO) of different pharmacological treatments was tested in 2 different labs using rats. Each experiment was performed at least once, but some rats were tested 4 times for example.

The exp design looks more or less like this:

[image: Hierarchy of the levels]

In R, I'm using lmer like this:

```
tS <- within(myTable, treatment <- relevel(treatment, 
             ref = "drug1")) #compare to saline
lmer <- lmer(ALO ~ treatment + (1|lab) + (1|lab:rats:sessions), 
             data=tS)`
```

being lab a factor with random effect, as well as rats. Sessions are nested into rats, and rats into lab.

Now
**question 1**: is the formula correctly written? does it show the hierarchy I want to establish?
**question 2**: is sessions a factor that should be included?

Comment: Are the sessions independent? Why did some rats have multiple sessions?

Comment: some rats had to be tested more than once because of technical problems with the electrophysiological recording. But the behaviour was uneffected so we wanted to include that data.

Comment: Are the measurements done during technical problems valid? Should they be included in the analysis?

Comment: If the behavioral response is unaffected I don't see why not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the sessions are independent and have no effect on each other, and that all the measurements are valid (your comment `some rats had to be tested more than once because of technical problems with the electrophysiological recording` seems to suggest these values might be suspect?) then:

**Question 1**: `ALO ~ treatment + (1|lab/rats)` (although your formulation also works, without session) if you want to vary the intercept among labs and among rats within labs,
**Question 2**: I would not include it, as it brings no new information.